# Student loan repayment strategy - pay little by little or a big chunk at once before interests kick in?

Tags: investing, etf, student-loan, repayment

I am a 29-year-old student who was graduated this month and looking for an apartment to rent.

I have a job offer for $109K/year but that won’t start until September.

$145K student loan with the interest of about 6% which starts accumulating from November.

Have $130K in my investment account(cash and ETFs).

What would be a good strategy to pay off the loans?
Would you pay a big chunk of if before November to pay less interest overall? Would you keep the money and pay as you earn?
Is having less money aside and less debt better than having more money in an account but pay greater amount in total? (Higher interests)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How much of that $130 is cash?   What is it earning?

Comment: Given that income, presumably you aren't going to get a write off in some decades for public service?

Comment: $130K, of course.

Comment: do you feel that your investment account is likely to go up or down before november? a lot of people are predicting the stock market will crash *a lot* and most people will lose their jobs as well, but a lot of other people are predicting it won't and they won't.

Answer (score 2):

(Hopefully this isn't too rambly.)

*Math* says that the most efficient way to pay off a 6% loan which starts accruing interest in five months is to put *X* dollars into a (relatively) high yield savings account (Ally, for example, currently yields 3.85%, which is *probably* higher than what a money market fund currently earns), and then use that enlarged account balance in late October to pay down the SL.

(Of course, the *much more efficient* path is to pay off all your *much higher rate* CC debts, then work to live below your means.)

(You must pay income tax on that interest, so squirrel some away for that.  How much depends on what your *effective* tax rate will be for this year.)

The big question, of course, is how much of your cash to put towards the loan.  We can't really answer that, if we don't know how much *cash* (technically, a money market fund) is in that $130K.

We *can*, though give you guidance on how much cash you should have in an Emergency Fund: 3-12 months<sup>*</sup> of "tightened belt" monthly expenses.<sup>**</sup>

Why even have an Emergency Fund, when you're losing money on it?  Because **it's insurance** against having to live for months on a credit card (which would be *really* expensive).

<sup>*</sup>How much depends on how stable you think your job is, how easy it would be to get a new job with similar pay, and whether or not you have a POSSLQ with a job.

<sup>**</sup>Of course, you're just out of college, so you don't know how much your monthly expenses will be.